# Use DynamoGetItem/DynamoDeleteItem to get/delete multiple items

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

I have found a way to directly retrieve/delete a single item from DynamoDB as a `task` inside aws `step function`, but AFAIK, it is possible to get/delete only single item that way. Is there any way to retrieve multiple items by query: pk begin with..., or delete multiple items by stating array of pks to delete?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html . You can get multiple items and you can delete multiple items in one request. But you cannot do *"pk begin with..."* in a DynamoDB without doing a `Scan`, explicitly not a get / query.

Comment: Is there a way to run said requests as a `task` (from aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions-tasks) or I have to wrap them in lambda? My ultimate goal was to execute retrieval and deletion without the need to trigger lambda and passing result as output to already existing state machine.

Answer (score 0):

If the available Step Function components do not let you work with multiple DynamoDB records, then write a custom Lambda function using the AWS SDK that is able to work with multiple records.

Next, wrap that Lambda function in your Step Functions state machine structure. You can get the exact business requirements you need by writing your own Lambda function. Like most software, you have more control using an SDK as opposed to using out of the box components.